# Reloading images gives error (image is shown)

Tags: jquery, image

I have this perfectly working code which reloads the image from the server each time the page loads - http://jsfiddle.net/6knfz8g2/4/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    img {
      image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
      /* Firefox */
      image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;
      /* Opera */
      image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
      /* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
      image-rendering: crisp-edges;
      -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
      /* IE (non-standard property) */
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      background-color: #0D0D0D;
    }
    
    img.resize {
      width: 400px;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    body {
      display: block;
      margin: 0px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    d = new Date();
    console.log(d.getTime());
    $(function() {

      $("#myimg").attr("src", "http://i66.tinypic.com/6fme5c.jpg?d=" + d.getTime());
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="myimg" class="resize" id="myimg">
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome shows this error:

> myimg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

While it works perfectly fine on local PC and in jsfiddle.

Can you help me find what is causing this error?

Thank you for your precious time!

Comment: compare the links while in local and in server by inspecting in browser

Comment: also check is that getTime() function returning time properly?

Comment: thank you - when I place this code online it still shows this error...

Answer (score 0):

I see that this piece of code is causing the problem:

```
src="myimg"
```

I removed it and it all works now without an error:

```
<img class="resize" id="myimg">
```

But I wonder how cross-browser friendly is this solution? and future-friendly?